# Adding doskey for an application in windows8

Tags: windows, git, cmd

Please guide me as to how to add **persistent** doskey for an application in windows 8.
Also tell me how those doskey can be made to work in git bash?

All I know is how to make **temporary** doskey as

```
@doskey ls=dir
```

And in git I know of aliases as

```
alias dir=ls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` to run a batch file everytime cmd.exe runs. If you add your doskey commands into that batchfile then every cmd.exe instance will have your doskeys setup.

See my post for more info: http://www.declancook.com/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: Declan Please also tell the steps of how to link batch file with auto run registry key?

Comment: Open regedit, got to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` the double click on the `AutoRun` key, in the value data put a path to a batch file you wish to run at startup

Comment: In my windows8 On going to the specific registry location There is no AutoRun.Now what to do?

Comment: I dont have a windows 8 machine around to test but if you run cmd /? you should get an output like this (this was run on win7 64 bit) http://pastebin.com/hGgNjVQv. There is a section describing where the registry keys are.

Comment: Your suggested link is unfortunately blocked in my country.

Comment: Oh sorry well if you run `cmd /?` and read the help output it says: when CMD.EXE starts, it
looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
either or both are present, they are executed first.
 
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
 
        and/or
 
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
I was wondering what the output of windows 8 cmd was.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49820/discussion-between-khan-and-declan-cook)

Answer (score 1):

`doskey` will load and work in a cmd.exe window.

It is not designed to work within other applications.

Comment: Please guide me foxi how to make doskey for any exe in cmd.exe since by seeing your profile you seem to be GURU of DOS